# How to return multiple views in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I’m just wondering if I have a  view with two partial views on it.  How can a single controller return more than one view?

e.g.
I have a search page with a search button.
You have to option to search by Organisation or a  Service.
I have created two partial views to display the results as they are different in makeup.

These partial views appear on the main Search view.

```
Html.Partial("_OrgResult") // partialview of results 
Html.Partial("_ServiceResult") // partialview of results
```

I have a controller like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetResults(int SearchType = 0, string SeartchTxt = "")
    {

        if (SearchType < 2)
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Search/_OrgResult.cshtml", GetOrganisationResults(SearchType, SeartchTxt));
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Search/_ServicehResult.cshtml", GetServiceResults(SearchType, SeartchTxt));
        }

    }
```

is this the correct way to do this ?
Will it even work ?

Comment: Did you try it? There is no reason why it shouldn't. But a better approach (better performance) would be to use jquery/ajax to call different controller methods based on which option the user selected and just update the existing page.

Comment: that's true. I didn't even consider spliting the controller methods.  But is the view the right place where that decisions should be  made ?

Comment: The 'decision' is which option the user selects which has to be done in the view. Whether you post the result of that decision to a single method via submitting a form, or via jquery/ajax to different methods is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to have a single `HTML.partial` line in your view:

```
Html.Partial("Result") // partialview of results
```

Then, in your controller, return the view that corresponds to the parameters:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Results(int SearchType = 0, string SeartchTxt = "")
{

    if (SearchType < 2)
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Search/_OrgResult.cshtml", GetOrganisationResults(SearchType, SeartchTxt));
    }
    else
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Search/_ServicehResult.cshtml", GetServiceResults(SearchType, SeartchTxt));
    }

}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `Html.Action("Results")` in view?

Comment: ok. So HTML.Partial("Result") will insert either the _OrgResult.cshtml partial view or _serviceResult Partial view.  There doesnt' need to be a link between the partial view name to be rendered and the name used as the identifier in the main view ?

Comment: Html.Partial("Result")  yeah that didn't work. It's looking for _Result.cshtml and I have two partial views called _OrgResult.cshtml and _ServiceResult.cshtml that it should be looking for

Comment: as simoco said, what if you try HTML.Action("Results")?

Comment: you will need to pass parameters as well